# Recognize user on website trough mac/ip/...? (phone)

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

There are other topics like this but none of them completely answer my problem.

I'm making a website only accessible for a small group of users. (like one team)
Now they should all have the possibility to go to the website and see information for them personally. And that without having to log in. Simply said: How to recognize a user without Login.

The problem is, those users will access that webpage 99% of time with their phone.
That means they'll access it trough WiFi OR 3G network making their IP not constant and in my opinion useless to track. Then I thought about the mac address, that's one thing that stays stable. But internet suggests it's not send to browser and so "unable to track".

Questions:

1. Is it really impossible to track a phones mac address or does a backdoor thing exist? (`javascript/php/cookie/...`). I do not want an app because the phones work on lots of different platforms.
2. Is there any other value or constant that I can use to identify a user without login?

Comment: why not keep a common password string for all the users of the website.just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could login via PHP-parameters,
so the user can save a link like that to his bookmarks:

```
intranet/login.php?user=vincent&pwhash=8fe4c11451281c094a6578e6ddbf5eed
```

Comment: he said user may not login or without login

Comment: yeah but then it wouldnt be save enought http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579721/recognize-user-on-website-trough-mac-ip-phone/14580013#comment20348525_14579793
And i think he ment with "without having to log in", that they dont see any login page and dont have to enter a login and password.

Comment: Exactly Vloxxity, I dont want them to input a login and password every time as they will check it about every half hour.
But actually this does not sound as a bad idea. If I can make them go to www.website.com/frontname.backname and let them save that as bookmark.
Letting them enter a personal code (given by admin) only the first time they visit that link and store it with use of 'localstorage'. (it stays stored on phone even when you close internet or shutdown phone???? I see possibilities now.

Comment: "www.website.com/login.php?user=frontname.backname" I mean.
(Maybe not the best way, but with the one time code I still have some controll about who can join)

Comment: dont try to make it much more complicatet than it is.
why should they enter a specific code?
you could just go with the php parameters(name & "password").

Answer (score 0):

You should use [localStorage](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) - that way your user can just login once into your website and then onwards you can always get/set that value.

Comment: But isnt it possible for other users to just give an other name when they first login and get other users messages that way. Not that they would ever do that. But just for safety reasons that sounds not very good I think? (But I'll give it a go for sure. Thanks)

Comment: Just create a simple one-time login in that case. Going the password-less login route using 802.1X certificates and device authentication is going to be too much of an overkill for the project you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible to get the user mac address so don't bother yourself to do some magic to get the mac address of someone's mobile phone. Well based on experience we developed device finger printing or DFP and gathered as many info as we can from the users namely external IP, browser info such us prefererred language, user-agent, etc., screen resolution, geolocation etc. Then out of that info we have some algorithms to make a scoring schemes or matching schemes then store the info to our database. Every time a user visits the site we gather again the info then match it to our records. For example user1 is then determined if he scores more than 90% matching to our records.